# How to avoid jQuery handlers dependence on activeElement?

Tags: jquery

I have event handler binded to document. It should handle, say, spacebar hit.
And I have some input, say, anchor or button.

When anchor or button are focused (which is reflected in document.activeElement), my handlers binded to document (or window) aren't triggered at all!

Why? And how could I ensure, that handlers binded to document would trigger regardless of currently focused element?

```
            myapp.directive('myKeyDown', ['$document', ($document): angular.IDirective => {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) => {

        $document.bind("keydown",event => {
            console.log('keydown', event.which);
        });

    }
};
```

}]);

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Added code. Actually, the problem is deeper. I use angular-bootstrap-select plugin. It relies on bootstrap-select. And its behavior is such, that after selecting some option with keyboard and hitting space, focus remains on Anchor.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where to trigger "blur" to reset activeElement. It's so deep inside third-party code. Or I should be independent of activeElement. My original question is about it.

Comment: I tried your code, it worked fine, even when focused on button or input text element. Did you try to putting it on a $(document).ready(function () { }); ?

Comment: Please, see updated code. I think it has something to do with Angular. I add this directive to body element. So, if some other element is focused, Angular doesn't allow binded handler to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

after all your code in keydown function.